# Prove that G is abelian if and only if the function $f:G\to G $defined by $f(a)=a^{-1}$ is a homomorphism

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that $G$ is abelian if and only if the function

$f : G \to G$

defined by $f(a)=a^{-1}$ is a homomorphism.

Assuming that $∀a ∈ G, (a^{-1})^{-1} = a.$

I don't quite understand how to do or approach the proof.
The only thing I understand is it's called an abelian when $∀a,b ∈ G, a * b = b * a.$
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You don't need to *assume* that $\forall a \in G. (a^{-1})^{-1} = a$: that's already true because $G$ is a group. (Well, you left that implicit...) To solve this problem: write down what it means for $f$ to be a homomorphism.

Comment: Write down what it means for $a\mapsto a^{-1}$ to be a group homomorphism...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the map $f:G \to G$ defined by $f(x) = x^{-1}$ is a homomorphism, then $f(xy) = f(x)f(y) = x^{-1}y^{-1}$ for all $x, y \in G$.  But we *always* have $(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$, whence $f(xy) = y^{-1}x^{-1}$ as well.  So for all $x, y \in G$, $x^{-1}y^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$; taking the inverses of each side yields $yx = (x^{-1}y^{-1})^{-1} = (y^{-1}x^{-1})^{-1} = xy$, and so $G$ is abelian.  Likewise, if $G$ is abelian then $x^{-1}y^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$, whence $f(xy) = (xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1} = x^{-1}y^{-1} = f(x)f(y)$, showing $f$ is a homomorphism. ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In general $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ (and $\ne a^{-1}b^{-1}$), but here ...